# OLAP cube in schema workbench measures shows no data

Tags: view, mdx, olap, business-intelligence, measures

Iv'e created a simple Schema in Jaspersoft OLAP designer. Now i want to publish my Cube in a view on jasperreport Server.

I managed to get this to work before with other Schemas but now i don't get any values out of my sum measures...

Can anyone see some Problem in here?

```
    <Schema name="AbsatzView">
  <Cube name="Budget" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="vBudgetDetail" schema="dbo" alias="">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" foreignKey="ZeitID" name="GJahr">
      <Hierarchy name="" hasAll="false" primaryKey="ID">
        <Table name="vBudgetTimes" schema="dbo" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Gjahr" column="Gjahr" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Monat" column="Monat" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="VersionID" name="Aktiv Version">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="false" primaryKey="VersionID">
        <Table name="vBudgetVersionAktiv" schema="dbo" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Version" column="version" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" foreignKey="VersionID" name="Vorherige Version">
      <Hierarchy name="" hasAll="false" primaryKey="VersionID">
        <Table name="vBudgetVersionV1" schema="dbo" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Version" column="version" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Absatz Plan" column="PlanAbsatz" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Measure name="Umsatz Plan" column="PlanUmsatzLW" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

I know that this for example this mdx have to give me values in my measures but it's empty and i don't know why?

```
select {[Measures].[Absatz Plan]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[GJahr].[2013], [GJahr].[2014], [GJahr].[2015]} ON ROWS
from [Budget]
```

If i use the same tables in SQL and asks exact for the same Thing i get correct values

```
SELECT b.Gjahr,SUM(a.PlanAbsatz) FROM vBudgetDetail a 
INNER JOIN vBudgetTimes b ON b.ID = a.ZeitID 
GROUP BY b.Gjahr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select {[Measures].[Absatz Plan]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[GJahr].&[2013], [GJahr].&[2014], [GJahr].&[2015]} ON ROWS
from [Budget]
```

Or this:

```
select {[Measures].[Absatz Plan]} ON COLUMNS,
      {[GJahr].[GJahr].&[2013], [GJahr].[GJahr].&[2014], [GJahr].[GJahr].&[2015]} ON ROWS
    from [Budget]
```